# How to create a sum of alternating integers from an int array?

Tags: java, arrays

I am supposed to compute the alternating sum of all elements in an array. For example, the array with values **1 4 9 16 9 7 4 9 11** should compute

> 1 - 4 + 9 - 16 + 9 - 7 + 4 - 9 + 11 = -2

following code was provided by instructor

```
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
  double[] data = { 1, 4, 9, 16, 9, 7, 4, 9, 11 };
  AlternatingSum util = new AlternatingSum();
  double total = util.alternatingSum(data);
  System.out.println("Expected sum:  -2");
  System.out.println("Alternating sum: " + total);
 }
```

What does util.alternatingSum(data) mean? Do I have to create an alternatingSum method? And if so, what is the heading code for that method?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: You will need to create an AlternatingSum class and an alternatingSum method that takes data as an argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What does util.alternatingSum(data) mean?

It calls alternatingSum(double[]) method of AlternatingSum class. `util` is an object of AlternatingSum class, which is used to call this method.

> Do I have to create an alternatingSum method?

If the code is not there, this code will not compile!

You need to have an `AlternatingSum` class, inside which you'd have an `alternatingSum()` method.

So, YES, you need to have that code for this code to compile and execute successfully.

> And if so, what is the heading code for that method?

The method header should go as:

```
double alternatingSum(double[])
{
  // your code goes here.
}
```

as this method accepts an array of doubles, and returns a double value.

Comment: Upvoted for hints as to what is needed, not just giving the answer to an assignment,  Let people learn for themselves, guys

Comment: @MrB I am trying to learn for myself. Notice how I didn't ask for the entire code.

Comment: And @Am_I_Helpful thank you for your guidance. I finished my code. :D

Answer (score 0):

Here is your method,

```
public double alternatingSum(double in) {
double alternatingSum = in;
if(data != null || dataSize > 0) {
    for(int i = 0; i < dataSize; i = i + 2) {
        alternatingSum += data[i];
    }
    for(int i = 1; i < dataSize; i = i + 2) {
        alternatingSum -= data[i];
    }
}
return alternatingSum;
}
```

[I found it here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10053405/6780362)

Comment: Don't just give the code! A bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example using Java 8 streams:

```
double[] data = { 1, 4, 9, 16, 9, 7, 4, 9, 11 };
double result = IntStream.range(0, data.length)
    .mapToDouble(i  -> i)
    .map(i -> i % 2 == 0 ? data[(int)i] : data[(int)i]*-1)
    .sum();
System.out.println(result);
```